# Error : -[NSURL rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000a0de0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I need help identifying my error. Does anyone know why it errors?

```
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSString *filePath = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);

*CODE WORKS UP TO HERE*

        NSString *strTemp = [self extractString:filePath toLookFor:@"//" skipForwardX:2 toStopBefore:@".png"];
        NSLog(@"%@",strTemp);


        NSString *copyScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ /tmp/%@.png", strTemp, myString];
        strTemp = [[NSString alloc] init];

        NSString *path = @"/Applications/APP.app/Contents/Resources/copy.sh";
        NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:copyScript, nil];
        [[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];

        NSString* linkName = @"/tmp/";
        NSString* extension = @".png";
        NSString* fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", linkName, myString, extension];
        urlPathOfFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL/%@%@", myString, extension];

        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath];

        action = upload;
        [self runAction];
```

Is it a memory error because I have too many strings?

Comment: It's because you're calling `rangeOfString` on an NSURL, as the exception plainly tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a high probability that `filePath` points to a `NSURL` object, not `NSString`.